# convert xterm256 to ansi

Tags: text-processing, colors, text-formatting

I have a program that will only accept ANSI color input but I have reason to feed it the output of a program that outputs xterm256 color codes.  Is there a converter?  I realize of course that color resolution must be lost, but closest color match will have to do.

Comment: Various versions of `xterm` support several different ways to output colour. Which ones in particular does your program use. Can you give us a sample?

Comment: If it's about the `\e[{3,4}8;5;<n>m` escape sequences that use a 256 colour palette, see [RGB values of the colors in the Ansi extended colors index (17-255)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27159322) on SO. See also https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#color_by_number. In any case the exact shade of the 8 ANSI colours are not standardized and are configurable

Comment: I'm thinking of the 'xterm256' colors used by my terminal. 'highlight -O xterm256' and 'pygmentize -f terminal256' both write the same codes. As you say they seem to all start with '38;5'; ...' It would be nice to be able to make a conversion but it doesn't seem likely.

Answer (score 0):

Never heard of such tool. But you can easily do a double conversion `ansi2gif` - `gif2ansi`. Or any other graphics format, like `png` or `tiff`.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems like no such tool exists. I made one: [xterm2ansi](https://github.com/zaidhaan/xterm2ansi).

It works by mapping all 256 xterm colors to hex codes, and then mapping the 16 ANSI colors to their RGB values as would be presented on xterm. Then it finds the ANSI color that is closest to the xterm color by calculating the minimum distance of the colors' RGB components.

Example:

```bash
echo -e "\033[38;5;80mcyan\033[m" | xterm2ansi | cat -v
# ^[[36mcyan^[[m
```